# How to append url last id in into search box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Im trying to append the last id of the URL into the search box of a DataTable. My URL looks like this:

Here I want to get the `CL00074` value and append into the search box, like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
<style>
    thead {
        .fix-search & {
            position: fixed;
            top: 10px;
            input {
                width: 250px;
            }
        }
    }
</style>

<script>  
    //this is for search 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 'no-sort',
                "orderable": false
            });
        });
</script>
<script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    // alert(id);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTables-example').append(id);
    });
</script>
```

If you don't understand what I'm asking, let me know guys. Any help is much appreciated

->Thank you guys fro your reply @Rory McCrossan and @Jameel Ahmed Ansari. I have find the solutions .

```
    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// alert(id);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTables-example_filter input').val(id);
    $('#dataTables-example_filter input').keyup();
});
```

Comment: Note that you appear to be missing a `})` in your code, but I assume that's just a typo in the question. Also, you can join two `<script>` blocks in to one, and the `$(document).ready` handlers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to retrieve the required part of the URL it would be easier to split it in to an array and retrieve the final element. You can then use the `fnFilter()` method of the dataTable to programmatically search for that value:

```
var dt = $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
    // setup here
});

var id = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
dt.fnFilter(id); // perform the search.
```

Comment: Thank you guys fro your reply @Rory McCrossan and Jameel Ahmed Ansari. I have find the solutions                                                                                                             <pre> var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// alert(id);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTables-example_filter input').val(id);
    $('#dataTables-example_filter input').keyup();
});

Comment: That may work, but it's not ideal faking user events when you have a direct hook in to the dataTables library by using the `fnFilter()` method as I outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var dt = $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
    // setup data table here
});

 l=location.href; // to get current URL
    // or 
    l="http://localhost/eezyclinic/Admin/clinicsubmissionslist/CL00074";

     url_arr = l.split("/") ;
     id = url_arr[url_arr.length-1];
    dt.fnFilter(id);

 });
```

Comment: Calling `append()` on a `table` element with a text value will just get you some  invalid HTML.